# Pandas: Sort number of words in one column by the values of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns: `df[upvotes]` and `df[headline]`. The headlines column contains rows with headline strings, and the upvotes column is just rows with integers.

Using pandas, I would like to find which number of words in a headline lead to the most upvotes.

What is the best way to do this?

So far I have this, however the apply method is passing a series to `x`, so obviously I don't understand how this works well enough.

```
df.groupby('upvotes')['headline'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(' '))).sort_index(ascending=False)
```

First 5 lines of data:

```
   upvotes                                           headline                  
0        1  Software: Sadly we did adopt from the construc...                  
1        1   Google’s Stock Split Means More Control for L...                  
2        1  SSL DOS attack tool released exploiting negoti...                  
3       67       Immutability and Blocks Lambdas and Closures                  
4        1         Comment optimiser la vitesse de Wordpress?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you can use `groupby.mean` for this. You can replace with `groupby.sum` if that's what you need.

In general, it's a good idea to avoid `lambda` functions where possible.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'upvotes': [1, 1, 1, 67, 1],
                   'headline': ['Software: Sadly we did adopt from the', 'Google’s Stock Split Means More Control for',
                                'SSL DOS attack tool released exploiting', 'Immutability and Blocks Lambdas and Closures',
                                'Comment optimiser la vitesse de Wordpress? ']})

df['wordcount'] = df['headline'].str.split().map(len)

df = df.groupby('wordcount', as_index=False)['upvotes'].mean()\
       .sort_values('upvotes', ascending=False)

print(df)

#    wordcount  upvotes
# 0          6       23
# 1          7        1
```